# How to correctly append variables to a link as a query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a Wordpress plugin, which sends users notification emails. Within such an email, I know want to embed a ahref link, which passes certain variables as a query parameter.

Currently I use two variables in my plugin:

```
$email (the email address of the user)
$scheduler->post (the name of the post, from which a user has activated the notification plugin)
```

I now want to create an ahref link, which appends both variables to the URL, so that I can access them in the form users are being directed to when clicking the link.

The aim is to create a URL like this:

```
www.website.com/form?email=example@example.com&postname=example
```

How can I achieve this? How should the URL look like?

Like this?

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/?email=$email&postname=$scheduler->post">Visit this link</a>
```

Thanks for your help.

Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape the variables before adding to the URL. PHP includes the [`http_build_query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) function which will build the query string using variables in an array, example usage:

```
$email = 'example@example.com';
$postname = 'postname';
$url = 'http://www.example.com/';

$queryString = http_build_query(array(
    'email' => $email,
    'postname' => $postname
));

$link = '<a href="' . $url . . '?' . $queryString . '">Visit this link</a>';
```

---

Also see PHP's [`urlencode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function which could be used instead of `http_build_query()`.